# How to stop links from covering subgraph titles with Mermaid graphs?

Tags: flowchart, mermaid

I'm using Mermaid in Obsidian and Wordpress. In both, the following short diagram has the connecting arrows covering the title:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this without CSS or changing to horizontal?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/9.0.1/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<div class="mermaid">
flowchart TD
    subgraph "your home"
        host(You open a connection to a home server)
    end
    subgraph "fast peering"
        host<-->fast1(I'm super close to the destination)
        fast1<--what a quick trip! -->server(destination server)
    end
    subgraph "slow peering"
        host<-->server2(I'm still far away)
        server2<-- this takes a few milliseconds-->server3(Still too far...)
        server3<-- this takes a few more milliseconds-->server4(are we there yet?)
        server4<-- this takes precious milliseconds-->server5(almost there!)
        server5<-- whew, finally! -->server
    end
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an explicit id for the subgraph, e.g. `subgraph FP [fast peering]`. Then, set the direction to the subgraph, e.g. `Home <---> FP`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/9.0.1/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<div class="mermaid">
flowchart TD
    subgraph Home [your home]
        host(You open a connection to a home server)
    end
    subgraph FP [fast peering]
        fast1(I'm super close to the destination)
        fast1<--what a quick trip! -->server(destination server)
    end
    subgraph SP [slow peering]
        server2(I'm still far away)
        server2<-- this takes a few milliseconds-->server3(Still too far...)
        server3<-- this takes a few more milliseconds-->server4(are we there yet?)
        server4<-- this takes precious milliseconds-->server5(almost there!)
        server5<-- whew, finally! -->server
    end
    Home <---> FP
    Home <---> SP
</div>
```

Comment: Cool if this fixes the OP's problem, but it doesn't really solve the problem when you want to target nodes within a sub-graph, and not just draw edges between the boundaries of the sub-graphs.